# Receber e manipular dados de uma query

Tags: c#, query

Gostaria de saber como manipular os dados de uma `query`. 
Tenho um metodo que realiza um `Select`, e eu to criando uma `List` pra armazenar os resultados, e retornando essa lista. **Mas como eu posso utilizar esses dados fora do metodo?**

Segue:

```
public List<Results> GetInfo(long id)
        {
            var Id = id;
            using (var conn = DatabaseUtil.GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = $@"SELECT
                                            cb.id AS Id,
                                            p.first_name AS FirstName, 
                                            p.last_name AS LastName,  
                                            cb.date AS Date         
                                        FROM
                                            st_compania cb
                                            JOIN st_pessoa p ON (p.id = cb.compania_id)
                                        WHERE
                                            cb.id = @Id

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Id;

                var resultList = new List<Results>();

                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(DatabaseUtil.RetryPolicy))
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        resultList.Add(new Results
                        {
                          Id = Convert.ToInt64(dr["Id"]),
                          FirstName = Convert.ToString(dr["FirstName"]),
                          LastName = Convert.ToString(dr["LastName"]),
                          Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"])
                        });
                    }
                }
                return resultList;
            }

        }
```

Bom, o Select funciona, mas como eu posso usar esses resultados que eu coletei, vamos dizer numa page, onde eu queira exibir o Nome e o Sobrenome da pessoa e a data num **Label**? Eu teria que fazer algo assim:

```
lblResult.Text = $"Nome: {resultList[1]}, Sobrenome: {resultList[2]} com a data de: {resultList[3]}."
```

Comment: mas você já retorna o `List<Results>`, isso não é suficiente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var resultList= GetInfo(1)
foreach (var result in resultList)
{
  Console.WriteLine(result.FirstName);
  Console.WriteLine(result.Date);
}
```

Comment: O Foreach tinha passado pela minha mente, mas eu tinha me esquecido dele. Muito obrigado!